# Producer Consumer with Java (Streams) Multi [Threading/Processing]

Tags: java, multithreading, lambda, aws-lambda, java-stream

I am working on a project with is essentially a long chain of producer/consumer. This means that 1st process takes data from user (huge csv file), processes data line by line, passes on to another process/thread which consumes this data, processes and then passes on to another one and so on.
The chain is around 8-10 units long, each unit acting as a consumer and then a producer.
I have thought of using AWS lambdas for doing this. I could also use Java streams. The advantage I see in AWS lambda is that you could put individual throttling limit on each node.
So, if your node's job is to update a dynamodb record, we could throttle this node to match with the write units of dynamodb and so on.
Another advantage I see with using lambda is that I don't have to write code to manage multi-processing (or multi-threading) and my processing of data won't be dependent on my chosen hardware - I could also save cost by choosing a low grade hardware whose only job would be to act as the 1st producer, but I'd still be paying for aws lambda.

1. Is working with Java streams similar if I use Java lambdas and use them in the same way how I would use AWS lambda? Can I use throttling in Java lambdas?
2. If I use Java streams, is there an easy way to manage multi-processing (threading).
3. Apart from throttling and managing pools, are there any other advantages of using lambda? Are there any disadvantages?
4. Are there any other alternatives apart from the above two?
5. What if I want multiple consumers for certain nodes in the chain? e.g. Consumer consumes data, processes and passes it on to the next one in the chain, but we also have to log the data or store it in db.

Answer (score 3):

Looks like `reactive streams` (and not java streams or AWS lambdas) are the best suitable tool for your task. They provide:

- backpressure, that is, balancing the speed of consumers and producers
- parallel execution of all the steps of pipeline chain
- connecting multiple consumers for the same producer

There is a number of `reactive streams` implementations: JavaRx2, Project Reactor (included in Spring 5), Akka Streams and others.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you should use step functions to chain together lambda.